# How to create a record Photo in Rails with image url

Tags: rails-activerecord

I have a model in my database called product. It has many photos.

```
  has_many :photos, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy
```

My Photo model looks like this:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
  mount_uploader :image, AttachmentUploader
end
```

I want to add Photo for product p1, and I don't want to download photo previously, but to pass it's url instead, smething like:

```
Photo.create(image: URI.parse("http://www.zdenka.hr/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/classic.png"), imageable: p1)
```

However, image is set to nil. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Photo.create(image: open("http://www.zdenka.hr/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/classic.png"), imageable: p1)
```